# Go: How to convert a float32 pointer to float64 pointer

Tags: go, pointers

How do you convert a float32 pointer `*float32` to a float64 pointer `*float64`.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var value *float32
    v := float64(*value)
    vp := &v
    fmt.Println(vp)
}
```

The following code returns

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: As the error says, `value` is `nil` when you try to dereference it. It doesn't point to anything as it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Did you mean to include `var x float32 = 0; var value *float32 = &x` or something like that? https://play.golang.com/p/XlC3H1T7g9R

Comment: When you don't understand what's going on, "seemingly simple" is not necessarily so. You can't get a `float32` value to convert if the pointer is `nil`, hence you need a conditional of some sort to get it, along with a new memory location to store the converted value. If direct type casting were allowed (which you could still do with `unsafe`) you would end up with a pointer to an invalid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is failing is simply that you are trying to dereference a pointer that has not been initialised:

```golang
    var value *float32
```

declares a pointer to a `float32`, but does not initialise it, resulting in a `nil` pointer.

```golang
    v := float64(*value)
```

Then tries to dereference `value` but as we just identified, `value` is `nil` - it doesn't point to anything so asking for what it points to is bound to result in an error.

However, your code is actually fine, as long as you have *a `*float32` that actually points to a `float32`*, which we can see if we add an actual `float32` variable and initialise `value` to point to that:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var vv float32 = 3.14159
    var value *float32 = &vv
    v := float64(*value)
    vp := &v
    fmt.Println(vp)
}
```

Which will output the address of the `float64` value.

However, be aware that a `float64` is not just a `float32` that takes up twice as many bytes.  The precision and the internal representation are different, as can be seen with a further modification to the code:

```golang
func main() {
    var vv float32 = 3.14159
    var value *float32 = &vv
    v := float64(*value)
    fmt.Println(vv)
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

you should see output similar to:

```
3.14159
3.141590118408203
```

This is not a bug, this is the result of the different internal representation of a `float64` vs `float32`.

There is no way to guarantee the exact same value in these different types - each has characteristics that make some values literally impossible to represent, from which it follows that it is impossible to guarantee that `float32(v) == float64(v)` for every `v`.

This is also why you cannot simply type-cast the pointer:

```golang
    vp := *float64(value)
```

This is illegal because a pointer to a `float64` is pointing to something *fundamentally different* than a pointer to a `float32`.

By contrast you **can** simply typecast a `*int32` as a `*int64`.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to write a function to safely convert the float32 pointer to a float64 pointer.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var value *float32
    v := float32ToFloat64(value)
    fmt.Println(v)

    val := float32(1.2)
    p := float32ToFloat64(&val)
    fmt.Println(*p)
}

func float32ToFloat64(value *float32) *float64 {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }
    v := float64(*value)
    return &v
}
```

Comment: You can just return `nil` in the nil case, you don't need to declare a new variable.

Comment: Besides JimB's comment (https://play.golang.com/p/mbVEislliFU), this looks fine. You create a new value of the size you want, and return a pointer to it. If you want a float64, you're going to have to make one eventually. And if you want a pointer to something, you're going to need to store it somewhere. So this feels pretty much the minimum work needed.